# ASpxGridView Evaluation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, aspxgridview

I'm evaluating the AspxGridView.

I'm interested in peoples experiences of it and whether they would recommend it. I'm also interested in any insight into the following

1. Accessibility Support (to me it looks poor in this regard)
2. The quality of the Xhtml outputted
3. How to deal with change tracking and/or concurrancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good product with a lot of functionalities out of the box but beware of the size your page can get with that control, specially if you use it with the updatePanel. Of course, it's not the recommanded way to use that control (you should use callback) but you can do it (and in some of my projects, I must use updatePanel).

Product support forums works well too if you have questions or issues.